# How to access mutex created by a C++ process in a Python process?

Tags: python, c++, c++11, boost, multiprocessing

I'm planning on using `boost::interprocess` to share memory between C++ and Python processes. Presuming that I'll need a mutex provided by boost to make sure only one process gets to access memory, how do I get python to acknowledge and unlock/lock the mutex created by boost?

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two obvious approaches:

- Find an existing python wrapper for `boost`
- Write a [C++ Python extension module](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html) that provides a domain-specific API for your application

Using the example in the link above and the some guesswork, you'd have something like this:

```
   static PyObject *mySharedMutex_lock(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
   {
       const char *objectName;
       int sts;

       if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &objectName))
       {
           return NULL;
       }
       boost::interprocess::named_mutex mutex(open_or_create, objectName);
       mutex.lock();
       return Py_None;
   }
```

Obviously you'd need the other boiler-plate from the instructions at the link above, and to probably provide a way of unlocking the mutex.  Doesn't look very onerous to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

## namedmutex.py, a simple ctypes wrapper for Win32 named mutexes

NamedMutex is a class for using Windows (Win32) named mutexes for system-wide locks. For example, we use these to lock system-wide log files that multiple processes can write to.

This has a similar API to threading.Lock, and can be used with Python's with statement.

For example:

```
with namedmutex.NamedMutex('get_dir_mutex'):
    latest_dir = get_latest_dir()
    os.rename(latest_dir, latest_dir + '-processing')
```

https://github.com/benhoyt/namedmutex

Occupying a mutex is a call to `WaitForSingleObject`, with timeout set to 0 in order to receive a response immediately, rather than waiting for the mutex to be released if it is occupied by someone else.